# radio buttons misbehaving when another tkinter is open

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

While using Python Tkinter, why does an open window change the behaviour of the radio buttons in some other window?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

def close_button():
    raise SystemExit

# open first window
root1 = tk.Tk()

# open second window and display radio buttons
root2 = tk.Tk()
root2.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close_button)
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(1)
tk.Radiobutton(root2, variable = var, value = 1).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root2, variable = var, value = 2).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root2, variable = var, value = 3).pack()
tk.Button(root2, text = 'print selection', command = lambda : print(var.get())).pack()

root1.mainloop()
root2.mainloop()
```

This program opens the two windows corresponding to `root1` and `root2`. Here's what the second window looks like.

[image: greyed out radio buttons]

The grey dots vanish if I click on any of the radio buttons, as seen below.

[image: misbehaving radio buttons]

However, clicking the `print selection` button prints '1', irrespective of the selection!

On the other hand, if `root1` is not created, the radio buttons do not misbehave.

[image: no errors]

Clicking on `print selection` prints the correct value: '1', '2' or '3', depending on which of the three is selected.

So, my question is: why are the radio buttons of `root2` misbehaving when there is another window `root1` open? (I am using classes in my program, but I have stripped it down to the bare minimum in this example.)

Writing the `root1.mainloop()` statement immediately below `root1 = tk.Tk()` is not an option because my application needs to have both windows open simultaneously.

Comment: The problem is you are using multiple instance of `Tk()`. Never do this with tkinter. If you need more windows use `Toplevel()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never use `Tk()` twice in an application. Instead you need to use a single root window with `Tk()` and for every new window after that you need to use `Toplevel()`.

Do this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk


def close_button():
    raise SystemExit

root = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Toplevel(root)
top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close_button)
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(1)

tk.Radiobutton(top, variable=var, value=1).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(top, variable=var, value=2).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(top, variable=var, value=3).pack()
tk.Button(top, text='print selection', command=lambda : print(var.get())).pack()
root.mainloop()
```